# Is it possible to run a custom plugin when a new Dynamics 365 Solution is create

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am currently working on a project where I need to create a custom plugin for Dynamics 365 Sales. I have created a plugin that creates custom tables/entities in C#. I have managed to get it working to the point where I create an account (for testing purposes) to see if the plugin runs, and it creates the tables as I expect. However, I don't want the plugin to run more than once.

I was wondering how I could package the plugin and execute it when the environment is first created so that it only runs once and doesn't run again unless a whole new dynamics environment is created.

Comment: Should this be a managed solution and Admin can install/import after a new environment is provisioned ?

Comment: why not just create a solution and add your table to the solution?